# Gulp 4 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, gulp, commonjs, bootstrap-5

I'm using **gulp 4** in my project with **bootstrap 5** when I call the BS from **node_modules** the js did not work as I expected it show me this error message in my console.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

**here is my app.js file:**

```
var bootstrap = require("../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle");
```

**here is my gulpfile.js file:**

```
const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require("gulp");
const terser = require("gulp-terser");
const babel = require("gulp-babel");
const browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();

...

function compileJS() {
    return src("src/js/app.js", { sourcemaps: true })
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(terser())
        .pipe(dest("src/assets/js", { sourcemaps: "." }));
}

...
```

the **SASS** files work well but the js no I got that error message.

Comment: `require` is only available when running code in Node.js.

Comment: I find that I can use require in my js file by using something called babelify and browserify but I don't know how to implement it in my project.

Comment: I cannot help you with that and I'm not interested enough to investigate that for you.